# HDFS Yarn Singleton issue

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have an issue when i start yarn, I end up with some errors. what is this singleton issue ? how to resolve it?

> starting yarn daemons
>
> starting resourcemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn--resourcemanager-hadoop-master.out
>
> Nov 20, 2017 10:02:25 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   as a provider class
>
> Nov 20, 2017 10:02:25 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebServices as
>   a root resource class
>
> Nov 20, 2017 10:02:25 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider
>   class
>
> Nov 20, 2017 10:02:25 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>
> INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011
>   11:17 AM'
>
> Nov 20, 2017 10:02:25 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   getComponentProvider
>
> INFO: Binding
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
>
> hadoop-slave4: Warning: Permanently added 'hadoop-slave4,10.38.0.0'
>   (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> hadoop-slave3: Warning: Permanently added 'hadoop-slave3,10.44.0.0'
>   (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> hadoop-slave1: Warning: Permanently added 'hadoop-slave1,10.40.0.0'
>   (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> hadoop-slave2: Warning: Permanently added 'hadoop-slave2,10.42.0.0'
>   (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> hadoop-slave4: starting nodemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-hadoop-slave4.weave.local.out
>
> hadoop-slave3: starting nodemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-hadoop-slave3.weave.local.out
>
> hadoop-slave1: starting nodemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-hadoop-slave1.weave.local.out
>
> hadoop-slave2: starting nodemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-hadoop-slave2.weave.local.out
>
> hadoop-slave4: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave4: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.NMWebServices as a
>   root resource class
>
> hadoop-slave4: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave4: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider
>   class
>
> hadoop-slave4: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave4: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   as a provider class
>
> hadoop-slave4: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>
> hadoop-slave4: INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey:
>   1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
>
> hadoop-slave1: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave1: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.NMWebServices as a
>   root resource class
>
> hadoop-slave1: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave1: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider
>   class
>
> hadoop-slave1: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave1: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   as a provider class
>
> hadoop-slave1: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>
> hadoop-slave1: INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey:
>   1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
>
> hadoop-slave1: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   getComponentProvider
>
> hadoop-slave1: INFO: Binding
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
>
> hadoop-slave2: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave2: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.NMWebServices as a
>   root resource class
>
> hadoop-slave2: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave2: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider
>   class
>
> hadoop-slave2: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   register
>
> hadoop-slave2: INFO: Registering
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   as a provider class
>
> hadoop-slave2: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
>
> hadoop-slave2: INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey:
>   1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
>
> hadoop-slave2: Nov 20, 2017 10:02:27 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory
>   getComponentProvider
>
> hadoop-slave2: INFO: Binding
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
>   to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"

I face issues with namenode web to fetch information.
Below is screenshot for overview tab:
[image: Hadoop --> overview]

Below is screenshot for utilities tab:
[image: Utilities -> Browse the file system]

Comment: Why do you think you have a problem? The log just says its an INFO level message.

Comment: @BinaryNerd, the issue is that my namenode web is blank, i can only see data from utilities -> Browse the file system, other than that everything is blank. I have updated few screen shots for your reference.